# how to use char in a array?

Tags: java, swing

please I'd like to know how to make jtxtScore[6] show letter grade, It calculates grade average but I want to it to show letter grade too.``

```
public  class ScoreGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
      final int SIZE=6;
      JButton jbtnCalculate = new JButton ("Calculate");

         JTextField [] jtxtScore = new JTextField[SIZE];
       JTextField [] jtxtWeight = new JTextField[SIZE];

    JLabel [] jlblModuleName = new JLabel[SIZE];    

     JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    double []scores = new double[SIZE]; 
    double []weights = new double[SIZE]; 


    public ScoreGUI(){
        jlblModuleName [0]= new JLabel("Assignments");
        jlblModuleName [1] = new JLabel("Mid term");
        jlblModuleName [2]= new JLabel("final exam");
        jlblModuleName [3]= new JLabel("Final Project");
        jlblModuleName [4]= new JLabel("grade average");
        jlblModuleName [5]= new JLabel("letter grade");

        scorePanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        scorePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,3,5,9));
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE;i++){
        scorePanel.add(jlblModuleName[i]);
        jtxtScore[i] = new JTextField(8);
        scorePanel.add(jtxtScore[i]);
        jtxtWeight[i] = new JTextField(8);
        scorePanel.add(jtxtWeight[i]);
        //add(jtxtWeight[i]);
        }
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        jbtnCalculate.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(jbtnCalculate);

        add(scorePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public double calculateScore(double[]score, double[]weight){

        double grade=0.0;

    grade = (score[0]*weight[0]+score[1]*weight[1]+score[2]*weight[2]+score[3]*weight[3]);


    return grade;   
    }


    public char calculateLetter(char grade){
        char letter='N';
        if(grade>=90)
            letter = 'A';
        else if(grade>=80)
            letter = 'B';
        else if(grade>=70)
            letter = 'C';
        else if(grade>=60)
            letter = 'D';
        else if(grade<50)
            letter = 'F';
        return letter;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        scores[i] = Double.parseDouble(jtxtScore[i].getText());
        weights[i] = Double.parseDouble(jtxtWeight[i].getText());

        }
        jtxtScore[4].setText(calculateScore(scores,weights)+"");
        jtxtScore[5].setText(calculateLetter) // what do I have to do here?
    }   

}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

These lines here:

```
    jtxtScore[4].setText(calculateScore(scores,weights)+"");
    jtxtScore[5].setText(calculateLetter) // what do I have to do here?
```

You should calculate scores and first put the value returned into an double variable.

i.e.,

```
double score = calculateScore(scores,weights);

jtxtScore[4].setText(score + "");
```

You should then use the `score` value in your `calculateLetter` method to get your desired char. Note that you might want to change `calculateLetter` to take an double parameter and not a char as a char parameter makes no sense.

---

**[edited]** As a side note, while I applaud your use of arrays since their is simplifying your code greatly, I don't think that you should use them for the final two JTextFields, since these JTextFields don't all hold the same type of information as the others. In your code, I think that you'd be much better off naming these JTextFields, scoreField and letterGradeField, or something similar. Doing this will make your code self-commenting and make it much easier for others and for your future self to understand your code.

Also, I'd use a for loop here:

```
grade = (score[0]*weight[0]+score[1]*weight[1]+score[2]*weight[2]+score[3]*weight[3]);
```

rather than hard-code everything. This will allow you to use a different number of scores later if desired.